# I have disconnected the access of Clash of Clans from my account. How do I fix it?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What happened is my younger brother has disconnected the access of Clash of Clans from my Google account settings and connected apps and games, and now I am not able to switch to my village. What can I do at this point to get my village back?

Comment: Have you tried http://cocland.com/tutorials/how-to-fix-cant-sign-in-to-google-in-clash-of-clans ?

Answer (score 1):

- Open your Clash of Clans application and go to the settings.
- Choose the Google Play Sign-In option.
- Sign-in with your Google Play account.
- It will ask if you want the village with the old town hall back.
- Choose yes.